# EmEditorで一行ずつ青い選択状態で下がっていくにはどのようにマクロで記述しますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorで一行ずつ青い選択状態で下がっていくにはどのようにマクロで記述しますでしょうか？
この下がっていく合間に行単位でマクロ処理を行いたいです。

editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4154);

もしくは、
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4437);
document.selection.LineDown(true,1);

このマクロで矢印キーで一行ずつ行が選択された状態で下がって行くのは出来たのですが、前の行選択が外れないので矢印を押して次の行が選択されたときは、前の行の選択は外れる状態にしたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

やりたいマクロとしては、

これと組み合わせて
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199);

１行ずつ選択されて論理行単位のマクロを処理していく
１行選択→再変換マクロ実行→これを最後の行に達するまでループする

このため下に下がったときには前の行の選択範囲が外れてもらわないと困ります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

次のように、最初に選択を解除するメソッド `Collapse()` を追加するといいと思います。

```
document.selection.Collapse();
document.selection.LineDown(true,1);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。エンターを押して再変換を確定させて次の行に移るには、document.selection.NewLine(1);これとは異なる記述でしょうか？同じ命令をループして最後の行まで繰り返すのはどう書きますでしょうか？

Comment: 再変換の候補が出るところまではいけたのですが、そこから止まります。マクロ録画でエンターを押すとdocument.selection.NewLine(1);が記録されるのですが、これでは動きませんでした。